# Using a for each variable to return def list size

Tags: groovy, foreach

I'm using a map which contains string key and list values.  When using a for each loop, I'm unable to use my string variable to pull the size of my lists (commented out line).  My output for the below is as follows:

> Task :nametest
>   starting test
>   3
>   NA
>   SEA
>   EUR

Ultimately, my goal is nested loops to print all of the DC's in each of my lists.

```
    task nametest << {
    def dcMap = [:];
    def naDCs = ["10", "20", "30"];
    def seaDCs = ["40", "50", "60", "70"]
    def eurDCs = ["80", "90", "100", "110", "120"]
    dcMap << ['NA':naDCs];
    dcMap << ['SEA':seaDCs];
    dcMap << ['EUR':eurDCs];
    println "starting test";
    println dcMap.NA.size();
    def dcMapKeys = dcMap.keySet();
    for (def reg : dcMapKeys){
        println reg;
        //println dcMap.reg.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `dcMap.reg.size()` your code tries to get the value corresponding to  "reg" `String` instead of the value of `def reg variable`.

There are several ways you can follow to get your expected output:

```
1. println dcMap[reg].size(); 
2. println dcMap."${reg}".size();
3. println dcMap.get(reg).size();
```

Use any of the above options.